# ReDoc + SWAGGER + Spring Boot - response samples

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, springfox, redoc

Currently I am working on my API documentation and I decided to implement it with ReDoc.
My API built using Spring Boot..and for the documentation I am using SWAGGER. Everything is fine, but I am unable to annotate my Controller to show the 'response samples' part on the right in the ReDoc documentation. I have tried adding examples in the DTOs like:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public class DocumentResponse {

        @ApiModelProperty(notes = "XML reuslt", name = "xmlResult", example = "asdasd", dataType = "java.lang.String")
        private String xmlResult;
```

This is how my controller looks like:

```
@Api(tags = {"Document"})
@RestController
@CrossOrigin("")
@RequestMapping("/doc")
public class DocumentController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/doc-create", consumes = {"application/json"})
    @ApiOperation(value = "docCreate", notes = "Create Document", response = DocumentResponse.class)
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Document success!", response = DocumentResponse.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 201, message = "Document created!", response = DocumentResponse.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized!", response = DocumentResponse.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Forbidden!", response = DocumentResponse.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not found!", response = DocumentResponse.class)})
    public @ResponseBody DocumentResponse docCreate(@RequestBody DocumentRequest request) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing code samples of how you achieved this? I've been trying to integrate redoc to my open api project but no luck...

Comment: @Xander please ask it as a question, send me the link and I'll share samples with you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved by adding this to the controller `@PostMapping`:

```
produces = {"application/json"}
```

Comment: can you provide me with how did you managed to integrate redoc with springboot that would be a big help , i already posted a question by the way !